# Printing what is stored in pointer prints what is stored in that memory adress

Tags: c

When I try to print this

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
   int x = 3;
   int *ptr = &x;
   //printf("Address is : %d\n",&ptr);
   ptr++;
   *ptr = 1;
   printf("%d %d",x,ptr);
   return 0;
}
```

The code outputs 3 1, shouldn't it be 3 (then address of ptr?). Then, when I uncomment first printf it prints out:

Address is : 6356744

3 6356752

Does anyone know what is going on?

Comment: Passing a pointer as an argument for `%d` is undefined behaviour. There's a `%p` for `void*`.

Comment: 'ptr++;' - why would you do that?

Comment: use `printf("%d, %x\n", x, ptr)`. Btw you also have UB, `ptr++` increments the pointer to the next `int`. You are not allowed to read or write this location, yet you do `*ptr = 1;` which leads to UB.

Comment: Incrementing `ptr++;` and then assigning a value with `*ptr = 1;` is *undefined behaviour* because `int x` is not an array. You defined `int *ptr = &x;` and `int x`

Comment: Martin, because it was on my test in programing.

Comment: Also, in the commented-out part, you are are confusing a pointer, with the address of that pointer. It should be `printf("Address is : %p\n", (void*)ptr);` and similarly in the next `printf` statement.

Comment: Wather Vane I know but why would just giving address of that pointer make different output in the end ?

Comment: So what output did you expect? The answer is: it's undefined behaviour.

Comment: Because `ptr` is a variable, whose **value** is the address of *another* variable, `x`. But the variable `ptr` also resides at an address in memory. Those addresses are not the same.

Comment: The title of this post is funny. "Printing what is stored in pointer prints what is stored in that memory address". What do you expect then ?

Comment: Often in examples like this, we can explain what actually happened because it is something simple like `printf` using a value from where an `int` parameter should be because you requested `%d` but passed a pointer. (Although this behavior would not be defined by the C standard, various consequences occur from how compilers are constructed, and experienced people are familiar with them.) In this case, you have something a little more complicated going on, although likely not much more so. If you truly want to figure out why **this** particular behavior occurred, then you could compile your…

Comment: … program to assembly language (e.g., using the “-S” switch if you are using GCC) and then inspect the assembly language (both versions, separately) for clues. That is only productive if you want to understand more than just how C works—you want to explore how compilers and computers work at a lower level.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because OP asks to explain UB

Answer (score 1):

You have several serious problems in your code.

1) You print a pointer value or an address of a variable using `%d` but should not. That is undefined behavior so we can't know what will happen. To print a pointer value or an address of a variable use `%p` and cast to a void pointer like:

```
printf("Address is : %p\n",(void*)&ptr);
```

2) You write to memory that is not allocated to your program. These lines:

```
ptr++;
*ptr = 1;
```

make you write the value "1" one step past `x`. So this is also undefined behavior.

Correction the above could give you this program:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
   int x = 3;
   int *ptr = &x;
   printf("Address is : %p\n",(void*)&ptr);
   ptr++;
   // *ptr = 1;
   printf("%d %p\n",x,(void*)ptr);
   return 0;
}
```

With the possible output:

```
Address is : 0x7ffc5b0923c8
3 0x7ffc5b0923c8
```

but the output may change from run-to-run and system-to-system